# Selenium/Python: driver.get() works with home page, but not with specific pages despite changing user agent

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am trying to use `Selenium` to extract info from pages in a real state website, but despite changing user agent randomly with `UserAgent()` or logging in as user, it only works well within its home page, where it is possible to make a search and obtain a page with summarized info and the corresponding hyperlink for further details for each house. I saved these hyperlinks as a list and tried to use them in a loop with `driver.get()` without success, so I alternatively tried to do it for just one of those hyperlinks alone, which very seldomly worked unlike when they are opened manually in Chrome, so not sure whether there is some sort of IP temporary blocking preventing access when the scraper is used or I am doing something wrong. Here is an example for one hyperlink:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from fake_useragent import UserAgent

service = Service(executable_path='C:/Users/appro/Downloads/chromedriver-win64/chromedriver-win64/chromedriver.exe')
opts = Options()
ua = UserAgent()
user_agent = ua.random
# opts.add_argument("user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.3")
opts.add_argument(f'user-agent={user_agent}')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=opts)
driver.execute_script("return navigator.userAgent;")
```

'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/122.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'

```
link = 'https://www.fotocasa.es/es/comprar/vivienda/madrid-capital/aire-acondicionado-parking-ascensor-piscina/182698648/d?from=list'

driver.get(link)
```

[image]

Help appreciated, thanks!